# Why am I getting an "identifier not found" error when I try to create an object of this class

Tags: c++, class, object

I've declared this class, made and included its header and constructor, but for some reason it is still not letting me construct an object of this class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "gameBoard.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::ifstream readFile;
    std::string filename;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> gameBoard;

    std::cout << "Enter the name of the file: ";
    std::cin >> filename;
    readFile.open(filename);

    gameBoard current(readFile); <-- expected a semicolon error
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

`expected a ';'`

`syntax error: missing ';' before identifier "current"`

`'current': identifier not found`

This is the constructor:

```
#include "gameBoard.h"
#include<iostream>

gameBoard::gameBoard(std::fstream file)
{
    std::string line;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        std::vector<std::string> row;
        std::stringstream s(line);
        std::string val;
        while (getline(s, val, ','))
        {
            row.push_back(val);
        }
        layout.push_back(row);
    }
}

void gameBoard::output()
{
    for (auto& row : layout)
    {
        for (auto& val : row)
        {
            std::cout << val << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And this is the header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

class gameBoard
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> layout;

public:
    gameBoard(std::fstream file);
    void output();
};
```

Maybe you guys can help me out?

I am trying to get this object to read in a `.csv` file and store its data to a 2d vector.

I previously made all of this same code outside of a class in `main()` to test it, and it worked flawlessly there. Why isn't it working now?

Comment: Welcome! Specifically what line do you get the error?

Comment: gameBoard current(readFile); in main

Comment: Post a verbatim error message.

Comment: `gameBoard` is declared as a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` in `main`.  That variable hides the class that is also named `gameBoard`.

Comment: FYI, you may want name C++ headers as `.hpp` or `.hh` to differentiate them from C language headers.

Answer (score 0):

The `gameBoard` identifier exists 3 times in `main()`, but one of them is a mistake:

- one as a **class type** pulled in from `gameBoard.h` - OK
- one as an **object** named `gameBoard` of type `std::vector` - MISTAKE
- one as an object named `current` of **type** `gameBoard` - OK

There is no reason for the `std::vector` object to exist in `main()`, so you need to get rid of it (it is likely just leftover code from when you had everything implemented in `main()` before adding the class):

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::ifstream readFile;
    std::string filename;
    //std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> gameBoard; // <- REMOVE THIS

    std::cout << "Enter the name of the file: ";
    std::cin >> filename;
    readFile.open(filename);

    gameBoard current(readFile); <-- expected a semicolon error
}
```

Once you fix that, you will run into more errors.

The `gameBoard` constructor expects a `std::fstream`, not a `std::ifstream`. Despite having similar names, `std::ifstream` does not derive from `std::fstream`.

Also, you are trying to pass a `std::ifstream` object *by value* into the `gameBoard` constructor, but `std::ifstream` (and other standard stream types) cannot be copied.  So, you need to pass it around by *reference/pointer* instead.

Your `gameBoard` constructor should take a reference/pointer to a `std::istream`, eg:

```
class gameBoard
{
    ...
public:
    gameBoard(std::istream& strm);
    ...
};

...

gameBoard::gameBoard(std::istream& strm)
{
    ...
    while (getline(strm, ...))
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

That way, you can test `gameBoard` using any kind of input stream you want, whether that be a file, a string, a memory buffer, etc.